# comments made with fb page using graph api not visible to other profiles

Tags: python-2.7, facebook-graph-api

when commenting, using graph api(python) , logged as facebook page-the comments are only visible by the page creator profile itself, but not visible to all other fb profiles.

i have a page access token, and publish page permission. 
i followed the steps using post request as described here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/object/comments/

help will be appreciated!

Comment: please describe the issue in a way we can work with, including your code.

Comment: I'm using python requests module, with graph api docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/object/comments/

Comment: include your code in the question and explain which access token you are using

Comment: ive updated the question

Answer (score 0):

- Use a Page Token with the `publish_pages` permission
- Make sure the App is live (this is most likely the issue)
- If you create the Page Token in the API Explorer, make sure to select your own App and NOT the "API Explorer" App

You can debug the Token here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/access_token/

Comment: I'm using this permission, with access token i got from graph api explorer,  do i have to integrate using app id?

Comment: so you did not select our own app in the api explorer?

Comment: i don't have an app, i thought i could do it without it

Comment: you should always use your own app. the api explorer app is for testing only.